# Plotting function defined in a piecewise manner with Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I’d like to plot some function *f(x)* where *f(x) = x* for 0 ≤ *x* ≤ *a*, and −2 otherwise. And I’d like to plot it on a graph with *x* axes between two arbitrary points.

How would I go about doing this with Gnuplot?

Answer (score 2):

This is straight out of the gnuplot documentation ("help ternary"):

```
f(x) = (x>=0 && x <=a)?x:-2
```

After setting a value for a, you will be able to plot this function over any range you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
set xrange [ -4 : 4 ]
```

or

```
plot [ -4 : 4 ] f(x)
```